# What do some of these lines of code mean in python (Matrix Addition)?

Tags: python, computer-science

I'm trying to understand what some Python keywords and functions do by reviewing this code that takes in matrices and adds the numbers within the said matrices, but I'm having some troubles understanding what some of these lines of code mean. An explanation that's easy to understand for programming newbies like me would be great help.

Here is the code.

```
# input operation
op = input("Enter operation : ")
#if operation is addition
if(op == "add"):
    # A and B for two matrix
    A = []
    B = []
    #input dimensions for A matrix,
    A_row, A_col = input("Dimension for matrix A : ").split()
    #convert dimensions to int type
    A_row = int(A_row)
    A_col = int(A_col)
    #input, elements of matrix A
    for i in range(A_row):
        # input rows wise
        print("Enter elements for row", i+1)
        row = list(map(int, input().split()))[:A_col]
        #append row to matrix A
        A.append(row)
  
    #input, dimension for matrix B
    B_row, B_col = input("Dimension for matrix B : ").split()
    #convert to increate a matt type
    B_row = int(B_row)
    B_col = int(B_col)
    #input for matrix B, elements
    for i in range(A_row):
        print("Enter elements for row", i+1)
        row = list(map(int, input().split()))[:B_col]
        B.append(row)
  
    #create a matrix for result with 0 of size of matrix A size
    result = [([0]*A_col) for i in range(A_row)]
  
    # loop and do addition of A and b , store to result matrix
    for i in range(A_row):
        for j in range(A_col):
            result[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j]
    #print result
    print("result")
    for row in result:
        for x in row:
            print(x, end=' ')
    print()

#if operation is not valid
else:
    print("Invalid operation")
```

My Questions:

1. What is the purpose of that `[:A_col]` at the end of `row = list(map(int, input().split()))[:A_col]`?
2. Now this is where I get really confused. **Everything** from `result` afterwards seems to be a blur to me. Especially that `result = [([0]*A_col) for i in range(A_row)]`. What does that specific line mean and what exactly is its purpose in this code? The comment placed right above it does not really help me.

I know what bracket operators do but I fail to understand the purpose of that `[:A_col]` at the end of `row = list(map(int, input().split()))[:A_col]`.

Comment: This is not about one of your questions but something concerning another part of the code: `if` is not a function and shouldn't be treated as such (with parentheses). So `if(op == "add"):` should be `if op == "add":`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `[:A_col]` is called list `slicing`.
   The way it works is that given a list, you can choose take a subset of it by 'slicing' it. You can give it a starting position (default is 0) and an end position (default is end of list) and that's how you would slice it. In your case you are slicing the list from index zero until index `A_col` not including.
2. `result = [([0]*A_col) for i in range(A_row)]` is compiled of a few things so I will break it down,
   Firstly, you are doing something called a **list comprehension**. It is a fast way of creating a list from another iterable and you can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp).
   Secondly, inside the list comprehension you are 'multiplying' a list with a single element of zero to a list the size of `A_col` containing zeros.

Hope that clears some things up

Answer (score 3):

> row = list(map(int, input().split()))[:A_col]

The first part should be clear, the input string is split into a list, then map is used to cast all the strings to ints. The `[:A_col]` is a range accessor. `[i]` accesses a single element of the list. `[start:end]` returns a part of the list starting with element index `start` until `end` (exclusively).

The purpose is most likely to make sure that if the input is too long, it gets trimmed to the amount of columns in the matrix. I think the code simply breaks if the input is too short.

> result = [([0]*A_col) for i in range(A_row)]

This, like the comment suggests, creates a matrix of the right size with all zeroes.

> [0]*A_col

This creates a single row of zeroes. The multiplication operator used on a list results in [0] added to itself (= concatenated) A_col times.

Comment: This definitely helps! Thank you.

Comment: @0329 If this answers your question, mark it as accepted